# Using php file in notepad++ to connect to XAMPP SQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp

Hello I am currently doing a school project where I have to produce an application on android. Recently I began making the login/register page ,however I am new to PHP so i am unable to connect to my php file due to current errors. I was wondering if it was due to the database username being incorrect as when I installed XAMPP I was required to change the port numbers so it could work. The following code that i'm having difficulty with is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:8080"; 
$username = "root";  
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "db_client";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

Due to this I am unable to connect(connection) to my login page:

```
<?PHP 
include_once("connection.php"); 
if( isset($_POST['txtUsername']) && isset($_POST['txtPassword']) ) { 
    $username = $_POST['txtUsername'];
    $password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

    $query = "SELECT username, password FROM tbl_client ". 
    " WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
            echo "success";  
    } 
    else{ 
        echo "Login Failed <br/>"; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>Login|Matt</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login Example</h1>
        <form action="<?PHP $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
            Username <input type="text" name="txtUsername" value="" /><br/>
            Password <input type="password" name="txtPassword" value="" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html
```

Any ideas on the issue will be very much appreciated =)

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot connect to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the port 8080 from your server name. it is not the default port for mysql. 3306 is the default port.